# JSON data to struct not in data received order

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, parsing, decode

```
some: {
  "success": true,
  "data": 
[
  {
    "15-10-2020": [
      {
        "id": 100,
        "details": {
          "_id": 1,
          "_title": "My Title"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-10-15"
      },
      {
        "snf_id": 101,
        "details": {
          "_id": 1,
          "_title": "My Title"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-10-15"
      },
      {
         "snf_id": 102,
        "details": {
          "_id": 1,
          "_title": "My Title"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-10-15"
      }
    ],
    "30-09-2020": [
           {
         "snf_id": 301,
        "details": {
          "_id": 8,
          "_title": "My Title"
        },
        "created_at": "2020-09-30"
      }
  ]
  }
],
  "message": "Successfully Retrieved"
}
```

---

```
struct Response : Codable {
    var success : Bool?
    **var data : [[String:[Data]]]?**
    var message : String?
}
struct Data: Codable {
    var snf_id: Int?
    var details: Details?
    var created_at: String?
}

// MARK: - Details
struct Details: Codable {
    var _id: Int?
    var _title: String?
}
```

When i print and check the json data using

```
let dataValue = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
print(dataValue)
// This is fine
```

where as, after decode the data to my structure,

```
let Response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
print(Response)
```

the order of the data was wrong, what am doing wrong here, how to correct?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, any sample references >

Comment: I cannot ask them to change the json output, i need to work out in this end only. What was the possible way to do this

Comment: Sorry , I don’t understand....  I have provided my Json data and my struct too. Can u pls explain me in detail

Comment: When I post a question, it shows that my question has too my codes. If I edit that then it was not formatted. What I need to do, how I need to post?, Iam very confused here to post a question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223732/discussion-between-muralidharan-v-and-guy-incognito).

Comment: Hi Guy, using array in the above given json data, not clear ... can u provide me a sample data in array format in my own example. that will be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and effort. I finally managed to work out with an additional array of strings with ordered descending and mapped it with index of existing string value with the sorted array of strings for my record display purpose. Thanks once to you all.

Answer (score 0):

Probably only option to store them in order:

```js
const toBeSorted = {some: {success: true,
    data:[{"15-10-2020": [{"id": 100,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"},{"snf_id": 101,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"},{"snf_id": 102,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"}],
           "30-09-2020": [{"snf_id": 301,"details": {"_id": 8,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-09-30"}]
          }],"message": "Successfully Retrieved"}};
const arr = [];
const obj = toBeSorted.some.data[0];
for (const i in obj) { // split your big [{date:{}, date:{},...}] to multiple objects [{date:{}}, {date:{}},...]
    const subObj = {};
    subObj[i] = obj[i];
    arr.push(subObj);
}
arr.sort(byDateKey);
toBeSorted.some.data = arr;

document.body.innerHTML = '<PRE>' + JSON.stringify(toBeSorted, null, 2)
    .replace(/([{[\]}])[\s\n]+([{[\]}])/g, '$1$2')
    .replace(/(\},)[\s\n]+(\{)/g, '$1$2') + '</PRE>'

function byDateKey (a, b) {
    a = Object.keys(a)[0].split('-');
    b = Object.keys(b)[0].split('-');
    for (let i = a.length; i--;) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return parseInt(a[i]) - parseInt(b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

v2 arrays

```js
const toBeSorted = {some: {success: true,
    data:[{"15-10-2020": [{"id": 100,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"},{"snf_id": 101,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"},{"snf_id": 102,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"}],
           "30-09-2020": [{"snf_id": 301,"details": {"_id": 8,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-09-30"}]
          }],"message": "Successfully Retrieved"}};
const arr = [];
const obj = toBeSorted.some.data[0];
for (const i in obj) { // split your big [{date:{}, date:{},...}] to multiple objects [{date:{}}, {date:{}},...]
    arr.push([i, obj[i]]);
}
arr.sort(byDateKey);
toBeSorted.some.data = arr;

document.body.innerHTML = '<PRE>' + JSON.stringify(toBeSorted, null, 2)
    .replace(/([{[\]}])[\s\n]+([{[\]}])/g, '$1$2')
    .replace(/(\},)[\s\n]+(\{)/g, '$1$2') + '</PRE>'

function byDateKey (a, b) {
    a = a[0].split('-');
    b = b[0].split('-');
    for (let i = a.length; i--;) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return parseInt(a[i]) - parseInt(b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

or v3 keys seems to be in insert order @end ;-)

```js
const toBeSorted = {some: {success: true,
    data:[{"15-10-2020": [{"id": 100,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"},{"snf_id": 101,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"},{"snf_id": 102,"details": {"_id": 1,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-10-15"}],
           "30-09-2020": [{"snf_id": 301,"details": {"_id": 8,"_title": "My Title"},"created_at": "2020-09-30"}]
          }],"message": "Successfully Retrieved"}};
const obj = toBeSorted.some.data[0];
var k = Object.keys(obj).sort(byDate);
var obj2 = {};
for (const i of k) { // split your big [{date:{}, date:{},...}] to multiple objects [{date:{}}, {date:{}},...]
    obj2[i] = obj[i];
}
toBeSorted.some.data[0] = obj2;

function byDate (a, b) {
    a = a.split('-');
    b = b.split('-');
    for (let i = a.length; i--;) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) return parseInt(a[i]) - parseInt(b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

document.body.innerHTML = '<PRE>' + JSON.stringify(toBeSorted, null, 2)
    .replace(/([{[\]}])[\s\n]+([{[\]}])/g, '$1$2')
    .replace(/(\},)[\s\n]+(\{)/g, '$1$2') + '</PRE>'
```

Comment: Is this swift syntax.

Comment: Sorry Tom, i need those thing in swift. I have referred so many threads and found that json & dictionary data is unsorted, then how to change my json data format ... can i get any sample format based on my requirement.

Comment: Maybe if you reverse date content ? It is sorted alphabetically, so it should be yyyy-mm-dd to get proper order or yyyy/mm/dd that should be even more common. And it depends - for example under node.js small numbers are sorted properly, bigger and rest of key types has probably alphabetical order.

Comment: Btw this is non-sense **var data : [[String:[Data]]]** it could be either [[String,[Data]],[String,[Data]],...] or [{String:[Data]},{String:[Data]}, ..] I am using now. Both possible, but your suggestion would be an invalid JSON.

Comment: Now you have all possible an tested (Node.js / Chome) versions.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, the json data provided from front end (as a API call result) and am just decoding that to my struct and using it to display in app. As am new to iOS, iam struggling a bit here. Let me discuss with the developers in the API process and try to change the format.